# twitter bootstrap and ajax modal

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap

i am using twitter bootstrap in my asp.net project and what i have is a menu bar at the top. some of the menu items are supposed to open a modal with external HTML content. i tried putting an iFrame in the div which is to be become the modal. this does not work well in that it i cannot get the modal window to auto size to the content of the external HTML page.

i am curious to know if there any recommendations on how to correctly use the modal window with external content or any other jQuery plugins which work correctly with twitter bootstrap.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else comes here from Google... I found http://blog.assimov.net/blog/2012/03/09/ajax-content-in-twitter-bootstrap-modal/ helpful.

Relevant code (copied from the blog, not trying to claim credit):

```
<a class="btn" href="/path/to/your/page.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch Modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal"></div>

$("a[data-toggle=modal]").click(function() {
  var target, url;
  target = $(this).attr('data-target');
  url = $(this).attr('href');
  return $(target).load(url);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal

You can load in content via ajax. I use this personally. Also feel free to check out [www.bootsnipp.com](http://www.bootsnipp.com/) Great resources, including this one can be found there.

Comment: hi, thanks for sharing this resource. i am am using the same technique but i cannot seem to get my modal to size automatically to the size of the remote page

Comment: Not currently looking at bootstrap modal code but I am sure you can set the width and height to auto or pro-grammatically change the height and width based upon the content your loading, long as you know what it is. If not dynamic.

Comment: Thanks! This has everything I was looking for including stackable modals, ajax load and responsive layout. It's also compatible with Bootstrap 3

Comment: @Smegger No problem! They have pretty good resources on the resources page. I use a handful in everyday projects